# How to return div content only if another div is not present within html page?

Tags: xpath

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com"/>

<div id="" class="pgLinks">
<a href="/example-text" class="guiArw sprite-pagePrev ">&laquo;</a>
<a href="/example-text-2" class="paging taLnk ">1</a>
<span class="paging pageDisplay">2</span>
```

I need an xpath query that looks for this line here:

```
<a href="/example-text-2" class="paging taLnk ">1</a>
```

**and if the value is "1"** (which it is in my example) then it returns me the URL contained within:

```
"/example-text-2"
```

If the value is **NOT** "1" then I need to return the URL contained in this tag at the top of the code:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com"/>
```

URL returned: `"http://www.example.com"`

With help, I have got as far as this query:

```
concat(//link[@hreflang='en']/@href and not(//div[@class='pgLinks']/a[. = '1']/@href), //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[. = '1']/@href)
```

The logic works but I get a result of either:

A) "false/example-text-2" or B) "True"

What I really want is just the required URL each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(//link[@hreflang='en'] | //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1'])[last()]/@href
```

What this does:

1. The `(... | ...)` gets the link element and anchor element if it exists.
2. The `[last()]` takes the last of those found. Note that the elements will be ordered based on the order they appear in the document.
3. The `@href` will return the href attribute value for the element.

In regards to the question in the comments about including the main part of the url, yes, it is possible in this case. If you consider that the desired urls are either:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/example-text-2
```

You will notice that this is a concatenation of the link href and the anchor href. This is true whether the anchor element exists or not. To get the two desired urls, the xpath can simply be:

```
concat( //link[@hreflang='en']/@href, //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1']/@href )
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Just one other thing actually, do you know how I can return the absolute URL instead of the one without the main URL on it? Example, at the moment I get this returned "/example-text-2" when ideally I'd want: "http://www.example.com/example-text-2"

Comment: In general, xpath would not know what the main url portion is. However, in this case, it is possible (see updated answer).

Comment: Just tried this on a page where the link at the top of the page is a full page URL and not just the homepage. So this "<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com"/>" is actually more like this "<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com"/page-64.html>" Of course, this then returns me a result like this: "http://www.example.com"/page-64.html/example-text-2" which is incorrect. Any idea how I can get round this? @Justin

Comment: I think this answer answers the question here. Please see [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564416/xpath-add-concatenation-into-multiple-attributes) for an answer to your comment.

Comment: Thanks @Justin - I was really desperate to get this fixed so had to post another for this issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question now answered or is there still an issue with the answers provided?

Comment: This answer only works in the scenario that the first URL is a base URL with no folder depth. (i.e. www.example.com NOT www.example.com/folder-2) So the answer is useful for that scenario. I never managed to find out how to resolve the other scenario.