# XPATH - add concatenation into multiple attributes

Tags: xpath

Here is my code:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/page-59.html"/>

<div id="" class="pgLinks">
<a href="/example-text" class="guiArw sprite-pagePrev ">&laquo;</a>
<a href="/example-text-2" class="paging taLnk ">1</a>
<span class="paging pageDisplay">2</span>
```

When I run this query, it returns either the top URL on the page "http://www.example.com/page-59.html" OR if it a "1" is present here:

```
<a href="/example-text-2" class="paging taLnk ">1</a>
```

it returns the URL from the href which is:

```
/example-text-2
```

The thing is I want the full URL:

```
http://www.example.com/example-text-2
```

I basically need to add a URL to the second part of this so it joins the second result if present, so it is something like this:

```
(//link[@hreflang='en'] |  "SITE URL HERE" //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1'])[last()]/@href
```

I have tried concat:

```
(//link[@hreflang='en'] | concat("http://www.example.com", //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1']))[last()]/@href)
```

And so many other variations including using the pipe "|" but cannot figure it out at all.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: XPath 1.0 or 2.0?  I can't see an easy way to do this in a single XPath 1.0 expression.  How are you using the XPath (what programming language, etc. are you calling it from)?  It may be easier to simply extract the appropriate href from your XML using XPath and then use the facilities of your host language to resolve it against a base URL if it is not absolute.

Comment: I am using a module to do this so not entirely sure if it is 1 or 2. Also using php. (I am a novice)

Comment: In that case it's almost certainly 1.0.  I would stick with just using XPath to extract the (possibly relative, possibly absolute) URL and then resolve it against your base URI using something like [phpuri](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri)

Comment: I don't have the skills to do that at all. How do I find out which version it is? I have used loads of different commands etc and they seem to work!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the PHP code that you're using to evaluate the XPath expression?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have xpath 1.0 support, you can do the xpath:

```
concat(
  substring(
    concat(
      'http://www.example.com',
      //div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1']/@href
    ),
    1 div boolean(//div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1'])
  ),
  substring(
    //link[@hreflang='en']/@href,
    1 div not(//div[@class='pgLinks']/a[.='1'])
  )
)
```

This is an application of an [answer on implementing an if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045151/return-a-string-value-based-on-xpath-condition).

Comment: I tried an Xpath tester and this just returns "000000004B86DA
  $0000000000431118
  $0000000000430D3B
  $000000000042DB78" I have had to abandon this. I don't have the skills to do it.